# $n$ students divided into equal groups of $4$ with $1$ student left over or equal groups of $5$ with $3$ students left over

Tags: arithmetic

A group of $n$ students can be divided into equal groups of $4$ with $1$ student left over or equal groups of $5$ with $3$ students left over. What is the sum of the two smallest possible values of $n$?

Comment: I guess n is multiple of 60 =(4*1 x 5*3)

Comment: just realized that was wrong

Comment: I solved it myself but still not satisfied..

Comment: 4x+1 : (1,5), (2,9), (3,13)* , (4,17), (5,21),.............. .. (8,33) *.....................  33+13 =46

Comment: @user96335 Do you know Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

From the conditions we have:

$$n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$
$$n \equiv 3 \pmod 5$$

Or in other words:

$$n = 4k + 1 = 5s + 3$$
$$4k + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$$
$$4k \equiv 2 \pmod 5$$
$$2k \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
$$2k \equiv 6 \pmod 5$$
$$k \equiv 3 \pmod 5 \implies k = 5t + 3$$

$$n = 4k + 1 = 4(5t + 3) + 1 = 20t + 12 + 1 = 20t + 13$$
$$n \equiv 13 \pmod {20}$$

Because $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the smalles possible value is 13. Other values are 33,53,73...

Actually this is just use of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.